# Can't use tiny-secp256k1 module in expo

Tags: react-native, random, expo, bitcoin, secp256k1

I'm trying to create a bitcoin wallet from a mnenomic phrase using bip32 in an expo app, for that I need to use the module tiny-secp256k1, but it has proven to be difficult due to the apparent incompatibility with the expo framework, I believe I have solved various issues when implementing this module in expo but I am stuck now.

First I had the problem explained and solved in this metro [issue](https://github.com/facebook/metro/issues/815)

Then I had problems with RNRandomBytes.seed being null, I used this "react-native-randombytes" [issue](https://github.com/mvayngrib/react-native-randombytes/issues/40) to solve it.

But now I'm facing this new problem

> TypeError: (0, fs_1.readFileSync) is not a function. (In '(0, fs_1.readFileSync)((0, wasm_path_cjs_js_1.path)("secp256k1.wasm"))', '(0, fs_1.readFileSync)' is undefined)

I don't know if this problem is due to one of the solutions I implemented above or if it's something else entirely.

In my expo app I'm using rn-nodeify believing it would help me solve incompatibility issues and while it has worked installing some dependencies that were missing it has not solved the issue with tiny-secp256k1.

For testing proposes I've just been instancing tiny-secp256k1 in my app.js file, just doing that it's enough for the error mentioned above to appear.

```
import ecc from "tiny-secp256k1";
```

Any help would be appreciated.